# CSS: Offset the height of an absolute positioned element

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I'm trying to hack the normal behavior of a `position: absolute;` element so that it takes up the height it normally would and plays nicely with the elements below it.

Normally I might do a quick and dirty `margin-top: XXpx` on the element below it, but I'm using a responsive CSS framework and that breaks down as the viewport changes.  I need the absolute positioning to extend one section (white box) the full width of the page, where the other section fit within a wrap in the center.

What is the proper way to do this?

[image: The text in the red box continue behind the white box]

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to do this is use media queries.

Check the following links:

[Mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es/)

[Developer.mozilla.org: Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[css-tricks.com: Media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Thanks
AB

Comment: I thought about hacking it that way too, but on the mobile viewport it turns into a fluid layout and this wouldn't cut it.  I ultimately decided to break the wrapper, insert the 100% of page element, then start the wrapper again.